# Error while executing R commands in Java for accessing data from PostgreSQL and doing computation

Tags: java, r, postgresql, rserve, rpostgresql

I am writing a Java code where in I am trying to get the data from PostgreSQL and doing simple computation on it(calculating median). First I am loading the RPostgreSQL library from Java code itself and then loading the driver and establishing the connection between R and PostgreSQL through Java. But when I am trying to fire a query command(which is used to get query from PostgreSQL to R) through Java then I am getting error as:

**NOTE:THIS ERROR IS RESOLVED.PLEASE LOOK BELOW FOR CURRENT ERROR(Script File Error)**

```
org.rosuda.REngine.REngineException: eval failed, request status: R parser: syntax error
org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.parseAndEval(RConnection.java:454)
org.rosuda.REngine.REngine.parseAndEval(REngine.java:108)
Rtemp.main(Rtemp.java:40)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

My current code is :

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXP;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.*;

public class Rtemp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RConnection c = null;

    try {
      c = new RConnection();

      //Loading RPostgreSQL library
      REXP x = c.eval("library(RPostgreSQL)");

      //Loading PostgreSQL driver
      REXP drv = c.eval("dbDriver(\"PostgreSQL\")");

      // Establishing connection
      REXP r = c.parseAndEval("try(\"dbConnect(drv, host='localhost', port='5432',dbname='r1', user='postgres', password='pwd')\",silent=TRUE)");
      if (r.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+r.asString());
      else System.out.println("Success eval 1");


      REXP rs = c.parseAndEval("try(dbSendQuery(r,\"select colmn1 from host_brnd345633456_table1 limit 10 \"), silent=TRUE)");
      if (rs.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+rs.asString());
      else System.out.println("Success eval 2");



      REXP ftch = c.parseAndEval("try(ftch(rs,n=-1),silent=TRUE)");
      if (ftch.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+ftch.asString());
      else System.out.println("Success eval 3");

      REXP res = c.parseAndEval("try(median(ftch$colmn1),silent=TRUE)");
      if (res.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+res.asString());
      else {
        System.out.println("Success eval 4");
        System.out.println(res.asDouble());
      }
#The line 58 error mentioned below in the error section is coming at this line
      System.out.println(res.asDouble());
      //System.out.println(x.asString());
      System.out.println("Library loaded successfully");
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if ( c != null )
        try {
          c.close();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't think that there is any problem with Rserve connection as for simple code like displaying version of R it is getting executed correctly.

Also there is no problem with the syntax of writing commands for R to PostgreSQL part like the dbSendQuery() or similar as when I using them directly from within R they are working perfectly fine. So, the problem that I think is in writing the same in Java(corresponding syntax for Java).

**UPDATE 1: ERROR 2 (THIS ERROR IS RESOLVED)**

After taking suggestion from @ on_the_shores_of_linux_sea    I have modified my code a bit but now a different error is coming as:

```
    Success eval 1
Error: Error in is(object, Cl) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'conn' in selecting a method for function 'dbSendQuery': Error: object 'r' not found


Error: Error in is(object, Cl) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'res' in selecting a method for function 'fetch': Error: object 'rs' not found


Error: Error in median(ftch$t31001400) : object 'ftch' not found

org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException: attempt to access org.rosuda.REngine.REXPString as double
    at org.rosuda.REngine.REXP.asDoubles(REXP.java:77)
    at org.rosuda.REngine.REXP.asDouble(REXP.java:103)
    at Rtemp.main(Rtemp.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am not able to figure out why the error is and how to resolve it

**SECONDARY QUESTION:** This a secondary question as I also want to know that is it possible that I can write the R queries or statements in a file(a special R format file or any other format file) and then make Java read the file and push the R commands into R so as to execute them?

**UPDATE 2: SCRIPT FILE ERROR**

The method 1 mentioned by `@on_the_shores_of_linux_sea` below is working fine now. I am also trying to do through method 2 but having some difficulties in managing script through Java. The Java code that I am using is:

```
public class Java_RScript {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RConnection c = null;
        try {
            c = new RConnection();
            c.parseAndEval("try(source("script.R"),silent=TRUE)");
            REXP res = c.parseAndEval("try(\"do_operation()\", silent=TRUE)");
            System.out.println("Success:" + res.asDouble());
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            if (c != null) {

                try {

                    c.close();

                } finally {
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

The error on output console that is getting printed is as:

```
org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException: attempt to access org.rosuda.REngine.REXPString as double
```

My script file syntax is:

```
do_operation <- function()
 {
 drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
   r <- dbConnect(drv, host='localhost', port='1234',dbname='db', user='user1', password='pswd')
   rs <-dbSendQuery(r,"select colmn1 from hostess_table limit 10")
   ftch <- fetch(rs,n=-1)
   res <- median(ftch$colmn1)
   return(res)
 }
```

I am not sure whether the error is in script file or my Java syntax.

Comment: REXP rs = c.parseAndEval("try(dbSendQuery(r,\"select colmn1 from host_brnd345633456_table1 limit 10 \"), silent=TRUE)");

Comment: I feel you dont require quotes for dbSendQuery, try the above change and check if everything is working properly.

Comment: @on_the_shores_of_linux_sea I did the changes as you suggested but now a different error is coming. I have modified my code above and have also mentioned the error that I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How RENGINE works is, it connects to Rserve session through a socket and sends the commands through eval or parseAndEval. R session is not aware of any variables created in Java so if you those variables in subsequent evals, it will throw errors

There are two ways to solve your issue

Method 1 - assign variables inside evals

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXP;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.*;

public class Rtemp {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
RConnection c = null;

try {
  c = new RConnection();

  //Loading RPostgreSQL library
  c.eval("library(RPostgreSQL)");
  //Loading PostgreSQL driver
  c.eval("drv <- dbDriver(\"PostgreSQL\")");

  // Establishing connection
  REXP r = c.parseAndEval("r <- try(\"dbConnect(drv, host='localhost', port='5432',dbname='r1', user='postgres', password='pwd')\",silent=TRUE)");
  if (r.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+r.asString());
  else System.out.println("Success eval 1");


  REXP rs = c.parseAndEval("try(rs <-dbSendQuery(r,\"select colmn1 from host_brnd345633456_table1 limit 10 \"), silent=TRUE)");
  if (rs.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+rs.asString());
  else System.out.println("Success eval 2");



  REXP ftch = c.parseAndEval("try(ftch <- ftch(rs,n=-1),silent=TRUE)");
  if (ftch.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+ftch.asString());
  else System.out.println("Success eval 3");

  REXP res = c.parseAndEval("try(res <- median(ftch$colmn1),silent=TRUE)");
  if (res.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+res.asString());
  else {
    System.out.println("Success eval 4");
    System.out.println(res.asDouble());
  }
  #The line 58 error mentioned below in the error section is coming at this line
  System.out.println(res.asDouble());
  //System.out.println(x.asString());
  System.out.println("Library loaded successfully");
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if ( c != null )
    try {
      c.close();
    }
}
```

}
}

Method 2 - Use a R script and source the file from code

file script.R:

```
 require(PostgresSQL)
 do_operation <- function()
 {
   r <- dbConnect(drv, host='localhost', port='5432',dbname='r1', user='postgres', password='pwd')\",silent=TRUE)
   rs <-dbSendQuery(r,\"select colmn1 from host_brnd345633456_table1 limit 10
   ftch <- ftch(rs,n=-1)
   res <- median(ftch$colmn1)
   return(res)
 }
```

Java Code

```
  c = new RConnection();
  c.eval("source('script.R')");
  double res = c.eval("do_operation()").asDouble();
```

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested in Method 1 but there is still one error when I am printing the `REXP res` as `asDouble()`.The error coming is `org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException: attempt to access org.rosuda.REngine.REXPString as double`. When I am using normal R commands from within R console then the final result is shown something like this on R console `[1] 1178.30`. Why is it throwing error when I am using the same commands through Java parseAndEval()?

Comment: when I am printing res as `asString()` instead of `asDouble()` then it is printing the error thrown as `Error in median(ftch$colmn) : object 'ftch' not found`. It is not able to find ftch even though ftch is defined in the previous step

Comment: I debugged and noticed that where I am using `dBSendQuery()` no error is thrown but when I print `rs` then following is printed on output console `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbSendQuery’ for signature ‘"character", "character"’`. I think the problem starts from this line onwards and hence there are issues in every command after this.Also I noticed in your code that in `dbConnect()` you have `r <- try(dBConnect())` but in lines after that you have `try(rs<-dBSendQuery())`. I tried both ways but no success

Comment: The method 1 is working fine now. The error was in `dBConnect()` syntax as the `try` should be outer wrapper. I am also trying to do with method 2(script method) but it is throwing error. I have modified my post above.If you could take a look at it and provide comment about error it will be good. Thanks for help!

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue with the method 2 also. There was syntax error in both the Java code as well as script file code. I have modified above to the correct syntax. Thanks once again!